# Azure Logic Apps updates

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-security

I got the following message from Azure logic app,which i am not able to understand completely

**Subject: [EXT] Action required: Update firewall configurations that filter Azure Logic Apps IP addresses
Update configurations to include new IP addresses by 31 August 2020

Update firewall configurations that filter Azure Logic Apps IP addresses before 31 August 2020

You're receiving this email because you use Azure Logic Apps.

We're making important changes to the range of IP addresses we use for Logic Apps runtime and connector outgoing calls. To improve traffic flow, we're adding new outbound IP addresses for Logic Apps. Due to this, customers that currently filter the originating IP addresses from Logic Apps (most commonly via firewall rules) will need to take additional action.
Required action
If you have firewall configurations that filter Logic Apps IP addresses, to ensure you don't experience service disruptions, update your firewall configurations to include the IP addresses listed here before 31 August 2020.*

I have deployed some logic app and haven't done any IP or firewall related configuration.

Can someone explain this in simple terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Background**

The IP addresses that Azure Logic Apps uses for incoming and outgoing calls depend on the region where your logic app exists. All logic apps in the same region use the same IP address ranges.

**Why you received this email**

> We're making important changes to the range of IP addresses we use for Logic Apps runtime and connector outgoing calls....To improve traffic flow, we're adding new outbound IP addresses for Logic Apps.

**Explanation**

> customers that currently filter the originating IP addresses from Logic Apps (most commonly via firewall rules) will need to take additional action.

Because of Microsoft's upgrade, the range of IP addresses may have changed. **If you have firewall configurations that filter Logic Apps IP addresses, then you may be affected, If you didn’t do it, then you can ignore this email.**

You said that you did not configure the IP address and firewall, **so you don’t need to do anything**.