# IP whitelisting for logic app with SFTP trigger

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

Recently we observed that the IPs have enlarged in MS docs and will continue to do so in future. To come around with a feasible solution and not contact FIREWALL team everytime when there is new IP inclusionin MS docs  [IP Whitelisting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=azure-portal#configuration) we plan to implement APIM for static IP.

But the logic app we have has a trigger when a file arrives on SFTP location we wonder how to achive this via APIM. Please suggest a solution.

The link explains the [IP change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63380004/azure-logic-apps-updates) but we are looking for a solution to come around this.

Regards,
Piku

Answer (score 0):

*By Adding Virtual Public IP of your API management to your logic ap IP specific ranges, that way you can secure your logic app.*
[image]

*If you want to Secure Logic app through Private Virtual IP go through this [document](https://marczak.io/posts/2019/08/secure-logic-app-with-api-management/).*

Comment: Thanks for your response... can we pick a file from SFTP location in a structure e.g. SFTP->APIM->LogicApp?